# Study the stablility of this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to study the stability of:

**(a)** Stability of $x''+kx'+(2k-1)x=0$.

**(b)** Asymtotic stability of $t^2x''+tx'+x=0$.

How can i solve this problems? Please any help, to understantd this problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) has constant coefficients.  Find the characteristic equation, and look at the real parts of its roots.  When the real parts are all negative, it is stable.

(b) is invariant under $t\to kt$, so I might try $t=\exp u$, and find the ODE for $x(u)$

For example, 
$$\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{du}=\exp u\frac{dx}{dt}=tx^{\prime}$$
So we get a simpler $dx/du$ for the first-order term.  Try to do the second derivative yourself.

Comment: Can you write more explicit the part $(b)$? Please, is to learn how to do it!!

Comment: I have an ODE test and i want to go prepared.

Comment: Really thanks, for the help.